# Select dynamic pattern matching string from a column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I was doing a query in oracle in which i have to update a col2 using col1 specified in col1 so data in col1 is dynamic i.e. there can be any no. Of **/**
So i want  ... Col2 be updated as trimmed value from the last slash of col1.

**Input**

```
Col1        Col2
a          data
a/bb        data
a/b/c      data
a/bbc/c/d/    data
```

**Output**

```
   Col1        Col2
    a          data
    a/b        data/a
    a/b/c      data/a/b
    a/bbc/c/d/    data/a/bbc/c
```

I tried it to do it using regexp_substr but it's dynamic. My query is working for only one or two slashes something like this [^/]{1}

So, help me do it dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSTR` to find the last occurrence of a character and `SUBSTR` to remove it:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c369e/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Col1, Col2 ) AS
SELECT 'a',          'data' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a/b',        'data' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a/b/c',      'data' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a/b/c/d',    'data' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a/b/c/d/ef', 'data' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT col1,
       RTRIM(
         col2 || '/' || SUBSTR( col1, 1, INSTR( col1, '/', -1 ) - 1 ),
         '/'
       ) AS col2
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c369e/3/0)**:

```
|       COL1 |         COL2 |
|------------|--------------|
|          a |         data |
|        a/b |       data/a |
|      a/b/c |     data/a/b |
|    a/b/c/d |   data/a/b/c |
| a/b/c/d/ef | data/a/b/c/d |
```

Comment: Thanx MTO .. it worked but there is a little update just look at my updated input and output if there will be a case like row4 then how last slash would be trimmed

Comment: @steve Replace both `col1` with `RTRIM( col1, '/' )` - [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a087e/1)

Comment: Thankx mam@mt0 i put rtrim inside the instr and it worked ... And i also added a replace function outside substr to replace '/' into '\'

Answer (score 1):

For your given data, this does what you want:

```
update t
    set col2 = col2 || '/' || substr(col1, 1, -2);
```

I suspect that may not be the general solution you are looking for, though.

EDIT:

I keep thinking there should be a better way, but this should work:

```
update t
    set col2 = col2 || '/' || substr(col1, 1, length(col1) - coalesce(length(regexp_substr(col1, '/[^/]*$', 1, 1)), 0));
```

Yes, a simpler version is:

```
update t
    set col2 = col2 || '/' || regexp_replace(col1, '/[^/]*$', '')
```

Comment: Hey Gordon  can you plz elaborate me this regexp_replace(col1, '/[^/]*$', '') part .... i did not get that completely

Comment: @steve . . . It searches for the last forward slash and all the characters after it.